# Creating a SQL script to insert data into a table (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert

I sincerely apologize if this sounds like the most ridiculously beginner question, but I'm just starting to figure out SQL. It's more out of necessity than learning from the ground up. Thankyou for any help though, I sincerely appreciate it!

What I'm trying to do is create a script to insert data to the following table:

[playercreateinfo_item.sql - github link to copy of the sql table](https://github.com/mangoszero/database/blob/master/_full_db/playercreateinfo_item.sql)

The fields/columns are race, class, itemid, amount.

How would I go about creating a script for this? From my basic understanding, it would be something like:

```
INSERT INTO playercreateinfo_item (race,class,itemid,amount)

VALUES (1,1,1,1);
```

But what else would I need? Like a header or footer? I'm honestly not even sure what a full script would look like for this! I also have to insert hundreds of different pieces of data, I'm not sure if there's an easy way to do it, or if I have to just do it manually. I'm so sorry if this is a horribly basic question, I'm just lost trying to learn. Thankyou so much in advance for any help! You guys are fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SQL script is just a text file with SQL commands. Usually queries are separated with a semicolon.

No header or footer required.

**Edit:**

In case of inserting multiple tuples, you can do a batch insert with INSERT like this

```
INSERT INTO playercreateinfo_item (race,class,itemid,amount)
VALUES (1,1,1,1), (2,2,2,2), (3,3,3,3);
```

Comment: So, I can create a text file with the commands and someone will be able to run it on their DB to insert the data into the table? I'm actually writing this for someone else's database since they aren't willing to do it. I don't have a whole lot of programming experience, just dabbled in python a little bit, so I feel sort of lost. Thankyou so much for the help though!

Comment: A text file is fine. `.sql` is no specific file extension, just rename a `.txt` file. The DBMS should process every plain text file, regardless the extension. It's just a convention so you see that it's a SQL file without opening it.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have one last question; is there a limit to how many multiple values I should insert? Is there a recommended amount when I should probably create a new INSERT INTO command? Or does it not matter?

Comment: You are very welcome. I have not done bulk inserting like that in a while. I would not do too many at once. But do not rely on me regarding that info. I suggest consulting the hints regarding `INSERT`-performance in the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-speed.html . You should also consider the option to load data directly from a file. It is mentioned in the manual als 20 times faster.